# How do I find forest areas over 1,000,000 acres with no roads?

Tags: qgis

I'm using QGIS and would like to identify all areas where intact forest is greater than 1,000,000 acres and not impacted by roads. In other words I need to identify polygons 1m acres + with no roads inside.

I have two global dataset (both vectors) - one of forest cover and one of roads. I would like to have a set of polygons showing these intact forest patches.

Comment: How do you definte "not impacted"?  If you have a large forest with a road through the middle, but the portion on each side is larger than 1m acres, are of those portions of the forest considered "not impacted" by road?

Comment: Are your datasets raster or vector? You probably need to edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Just updated the question. We have vector datasets.

Comment: @James A simple PyQGIS solution would be of interest?

Comment: Use Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Difference to subtract the road layer from the forest cover layer. Use the field calculator to calculate polygon area for the new layer. Select polygons with area > 1m, and save as new layer. This should get you started. Now you need to decide how to handle areas of forest where roads enter into the middle but don't quite cut them in two.

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks very much. I'm going to try your suggestion @csk.

Comment: @csk It's probably worth putting your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Difference to subtract the road layer from the forest cover layer.

Use the field calculator to calculate polygon area for the new layer. Select polygons with area > 1 million acres, and save as new layer.

This should get you started. Now you need to decide how to handle areas of forest where roads enter into the middle but don't quite cut them in two. For example, is this one area of un-impacted forest, or two?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One further issue you may want to consider is how you define the impact of a road on the landscape. This paper's methods describe one way to account for a buffer around roads by applying a logistic decay function (http://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms12558). In your case you may simply want a more simple approach, perhaps assuming that the road cut through each intact forest area is 20 metres (or 60ish feet) wide. The loss of area is small relative to large forest areas, but more realistic, and logically counts for the fact that separate intact patches do not touch.

Then per comments from @csk, using the `Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Difference` tool in qgis will then get you the new (e.g, split) contiguous  forest patches, from which you can then select only those larger than 1 million contiguous acres.